# Hibernate/JPA: foreign key = null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

below is my 2 entities:

```
package dev.proj.project.application.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    public int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Address> address;
}
```

```
package dev.proj.project.application.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="street")
    private String street;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="house")
    private String house;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="flat")
    private String flat;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="code")
    private String code;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",nullable = false,updatable = true,insertable = true)
    private User user;

}
```

I want to create User->Address One-to-many relationship, but if I made post request to /address:

> {
>          "street": "ulicanewnew",
>          "house": "5",
>          "flat": "2",
>          "code": "20-001",
>         "city": "warsaw",
>          "user_id": 1
>      }

user_id is null in my address table:

[image]

Why foreign key in address table is always null?
Do you see what is wrong here?
With direct sql inserts to db - everything works fine

Comment: You have to `setUser(user)` before saving `Address` object.

Comment: where should I do it?

Comment: Where you are saving your entities. How are you saving your entities ? Share your service and DAO layer code.

Comment: try `{..., "user": {"id": 1}}`! (or write some code, which maps "user_id" (in your JSON);;)

Answer (score 1):

I changed request to:

```html
    {
        "street": "dyr",
        "house": "5",
        "flat": "2",
        "code": "20-001",
        "city": "warsaw",
        "user": {
         "id": 50
        }
    }
```

and it works, but question for now: how to use

> "user_id" : 50

in my request, instead of

```
"user": {
    "id": 50
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below changes to your address entity.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private User user;
```

Comment: unfortunately still null on user_id in database

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length; 

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
     ...
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name = "user_id")
     private int id;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private List<DatabaseTable> databaseTables;
     ...
}
...
...
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "databasetable")
public class DatabaseTable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_idFK")
    private Customer customer;
    ....
}
```

Something like that works for me.